# What is the minimal possible size of an $n$-universal graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization

Suppose $\Gamma(V, E)$ is a finite simple graph. Let’s call a finite simple graph $\Gamma’(V’, E’)$ an induced subgraph of $\Gamma$ iff $V’ \subset V$ and $E’ = (V’ \times V’) \cap E$.

Let’s call a finite simple graph $\Gamma$ $n$-universal, iff any finite simple graph on $n$ vertices is isomorphic to some induced subgraph of $\Gamma$.

What is the minimal possible number of vertices in an $n$-universal graph?

I managed only to find a lower bound for that size: $2n - 1$, as it contains $n$-vertex induced full and empty subgraphs, that can not have more than one common vertex.

However, no upper  bound other than the trivial $n2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ is currently known to me.

Comment: That seems that my question happened to be a 16000 Get on [graph-theory].

Comment: (1) Typo: Surely you mean $V' \subset V$ (instead of $V' \in V$).  (2) Have you tried the first few cases?  For $n=1,2,3$ I get $1,3, 5$...  still working on $n=4$.  (3) What's so special about $16000$?  It isn't $16384$.  :)

Comment: @antkam, yes, I  also got 1, 3 and 5 for 1, 2 and 3 respectively. For 4 I know a 7-vertex example, which is indeed minimal, because $7 = 4 \ast 2 - 1$.

Comment: Let $f(n)$ be the minimum number of vertices in an $n$-universal graph. Your lower bound $f(n)\ge2n-1$ can be improved slightly to $f(n)\ge3n-c\log n$ for some constant $c$ using a lower bound for the Ramsey number $R(m,m)$. For instance, since $R(4,4)=18$, there is a graph $G$ on $17$ vertices with no $4$-vertex complete or empty induced subgraph. Now a $17$-universal graph must contain as induced subgraphs a $17$-vertex complete graph and a $17$-vertex empty graph and a copy of $G$, so it must have at least $44$ vertices, i.e., $f(17)\ge44$.

Comment: If $G$ is a graph on $2n-1$ vertices which contains both the complete graph $K_n$ and the empty graph $\overline{K_n}$ as induced subgraphs, then $G$ is a [split graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_graph), and every induced subgraph of $G$ is a split graph. Since the cycle graph $C_4$ is not a split graph, any graph contining $K_n$ and $\overline{K_n}$ and $C_4$ as induced subgraphs must have at least $2n$ vertices. In particular, an $n$-universal graph for $n\ge4$ has at least $2n$ vertices.

Comment: @bof I also don't think $f(n)=7$ would work, but $G$ containing $K_n$ and $\bar{K_n}$ means $G$ contains a split graph, but is not necessarily just a split graph, right?

Comment: @bof, you are right - I miscounted vertices of my example. There are indeed $8$ of them, not $7$.

Comment: @bof, here it is: https://ibb.co/WgwrgBM

Comment: @bof - of course!  sorry i didnt read your msg carefully.  should have known not to comment so early in the morning before coffee :)

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00039-017-0396-9

Comment: I discovered by trying all the possibilities that $f(5) = 10$: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jamestrimble/small-universal-graphs/main/paper/paper.pdf . Also $13 \leq f(6) \leq 15$ (I'm hoping I didn't mess up the proof of the lower bound!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Asymptotically optimal induced universal graphs" by Noga Alon it is shown, that the minimal possible size of an $n$-universal graph is $(1 + o(1))2^{\frac{n - 1}{2}}$.

Moreover, it is also shown there, that if $\Gamma$ is an $n$-vertices Erdos-Renyi random graph with edge probability $\frac{1}{2}$, then it is $k$-universal with probability $(1 - e^{-C_n^k 2^{-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}})^2 + o(1)$