# What is the minimal $m$ for which the independence graph is $n$-universal?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization, independence

Suppose, an $m$ sided die is rolled. Let's define the independence graph $I_m$ as a graph with the set of all possible events as vertices, and edges between two events iff they are independent.

Suppose $\Gamma(V, E)$ is a finite simple graph. Let’s call a finite simple graph $\Gamma’(V’, E’)$ an induced subgraph of $\Gamma$ iff $V’ \subset V$ and $E’ = (V’ \times V’) \cap E$.

Let’s call a finite simple graph $\Gamma$ $n$-universal, iff any finite simple graph on $n$ vertices is isomorphic to some induced subgraph of $\Gamma$.

My question is:

What is the minimal $m$ for which $I_m$ is $n$-universal?

I already know, that $I_n^2$ is $n$-universal, as for any graph with $n$-vertices one can chose $n$ $n$-element subsets (indexed with vertices of that graph) of an $n^2$-element set, such that their their intersection is one-element if there is an edge between the corresponding vertices, and $0$ otherwise.

I also know, that $m$ should be larger that $n + o(1)$ as $I_m$ has $2^m$ vertices and [the least possible $n$-universal graph has $(1 + o(1))2^n$ vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3246874/what-is-the-minimal-possible-size-of-an-n-universal-graph)

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious, but I don't understand your $I_{n^2}$ example -- how do the $n$ subsets translate to $n$ events with the desired independence properties? I'm assuming by events you mean subsets of $\{1, \dots, m\}$.

Comment: @user125932, in case of $I_n^2$ $m = n^2$. Thus the probability of any $n$-element subset is $\frac{1}{n}$ and of a $1$-element subset is $\frac{1}{n^2}$.